# Modify android WebView and create whitelist

Tags: android, android-webview, iptables, whitelist, rom

This is my first time I'm asking question on stack overflow, so sorry if my question isn't clear, but I'll try my best. This question is for android developers. So I'm trying to create a system that prevents the user from opening web pages on the phone, but ze can still install apps. The purpose is for kids that spend too much time browsing, or people that don't want to watch cat videos (religion reasons, don't ask). Anyway, I'm doing it by modifying the ROM, and I have a problem. Of course I removed all the web browsers, but some apps that are not officially browsers contains a simple browser that uses Android System WebView (for example, outlook, Moovit). I want to some how block access to the WebView, but I saw it's complicated. I tried simply disable the WebView, but than i saw that i can't connect to Gmail and outlook at all, because the login page needs the WebView. I think that the solution is to modify the WebView and create a whitelist, so only sites like Gmail and outlook will open, but others will just show a blank page. The problem is that I don't know how to do that. Can anyone help? Thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

You're going about it the wrong way.  If you want to block all but a whitelist of websites, install a Linux firewall on the device.  Then you don't need to modify every component-  if the OS blocks the site, nothing can reach it.

Comment: How? Like AFWall? Than the user can change it back and disable the firewall. Or is there any way to keep the rules after removing the AFwall? Anyway I'd like to have more details

Comment: You're building a ROM.  Don't use an Android app, use a Linux (Android is built on Linux) firewall and don't give the user access to it.  There's dozens to choose from.  Or just use ipchains

Comment: And even if I do it, still mail apps wont work. For example, if I want to send email to someone@example.org, and example.org is not in the whitelist, the mail app wont be able to send the mail. If i modify somehow the WebView, I can be sure that only web protocol will be blocked, and other protocols, such as email still gonna work same.

Comment: @admiau8 No, that's not how email works.  You need to be able to reach *your* email provider, not the recipients

Comment: And your solution wouldn't work anyway-  you don't need to use webview to display html.  If you're letting them install apps, they can install a web browser.  Or an app that has its own web browser.  The solution to not letting users reach sites you don't want them to is a firewall.

Comment: My plan is to create my own market, and apps like Firefox and chrome wont be in the market. Other sources will be blocked. So only apps that use the WebView is a problem.

Comment: @admiau8 You're still FAR better off just using a firewall.  It's literally what they're designed for.  And yes, it's the standard solution.  There are also plenty of other ways for internet traffic to leave the device.  YOu can spend 2-3 hours learning how to set up a standard HTTP firewall from one of a dozen tutorials online, or you could spend hundreds of hours hacking WebView, and need to redo it for every version of WebView that comes out.

Comment: @admiau8 Remember that WebView is actually a separate app that's written in C++ and is distributed on its own schedule for security updates.  So you'll have to redo your patch every 2-3 weeks, or leave your users open to known security holes.

Comment: So if I get your idea, if I want to modify the firewall and create a blacklist, how can I do it?